# Excel Date Hms Being cut

Tags: excel

I am trying to read a csv file using excel.

I am able to split the columns bu the delimieter, however one of the fields is a date time field like `2015-07-01 12:01:59`, when the data is split into columns the date time is changed to `2015-07-01 12:01`.

I have tried different formatting options including, Custom->0 with no luck.

The only way I can successfully get the whole date time to show is to place an apostrophe at the start of the column, however, if i have a few thousand records this is not practical. How can I get excel to quit being a pain.

Comment: What delimiter are you using?

Comment: @BruceWayne batarang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking it's just a formatting issue. You're on the right track to try the custom format. I selected the column header for the date and used "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" as shown here:

[image: excel custom date format]

Comment: aha, never occurred to me to scroll down. This will make life much easier, many thanks, you have saved me a few hours.

Comment: You can enter the desired format in the box where I indicate with the red box.